# Why should I use io_service::work?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm new in boost programming, and I've been looking for a reason to use the `io_service::work`, but I can't figure it out; in some of my tests I removed it and *works* fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `io_service::run()` will run operations as long as there are asynchronous operations to perform.  If, at any time, there are no asynchronous operations pending (or handlers being invoked), the `run()` call will return.

However, there are some designs that would prefer that the `run()` call not exit until all work is done AND the `io_service` has explicitly been instructed that it's okay to exit.  That's what `io_service::work` is used for.  By creating the `work` object (I usually do it on the heap and a shared_ptr), the io_service considers itself to always have something pending, and therefore the `run()` method will not return.  Once I want the service to be able to exit (usually during shutdown), I will destroy the work object.

Comment: Usually, if I use a shared_ptr to work, then yes, I call `reset()` on the shared_ptr.

Answer (score 8):

`io_service::work` is base class of all works that can posted to an instance of `io_service`, for example when you are working with a socket and start an asynchronous read, actually you are adding a `work` to the `io_service`. So you normally never use `work` directly, but there is one exception to this:

`io_service::run` will return as soon as there is no more work to do, so consider an application that have some producer and consumer threads, producers occasionally produce works and post them to consumer threads with `io_service::post`, but if all works finished, then `io_service::run` will return and possibly your consumer thread will be stopped, so you need an arbitrary work to keep `io_service` busy, in this case you may use `io_service::work` directly.